# Why does the %str in `%str(%inner_macro())` not work?

Tags: sas, sas-macro

%str should pass a string as one parameter to a sas macro, even if it contains commas, but that apparently does not work if the argument of %str is in it self the result of a macro? I get `ERROR: More positional parameters found than defined.`

### Example

This is what the error means

```
    15         %macro outer_macro(left, right);
    16          %put NOTE: outer_macro: left is &left;
    17          %put NOTE: outer_macro: right is &right;
    18         %mend;
    19         %outer_macro(left, right);
    NOTE: outer_macro: left is left
    NOTE: outer_macro: right is right
    20         %outer_macro(left, midle, right);
    ERROR: More positional parameters found than defined.
```

This is how `%str` resolves it in normal situations.

```
    21         %outer_macro(left, %str(midle, right));
    NOTE: outer_macro: left is left
    NOTE: outer_macro: right is midle, right
```

It is possible to construct an argument of a macro with an inner macro

```
    23         %macro blank_macro(left, right);
    24          %put NOTE: blank_macro: left is &left;
    25          %put NOTE: blank_macro: right is &right;
    26          &left. &right.
    27         %mend;
    28         %outer_macro(links, %blank_macro(midden, rechts));
    NOTE: blank_macro: left is midden
    NOTE: blank_macro: right is rechts
    NOTE: outer_macro: left is links
    NOTE: outer_macro: right is midden rechts
```

But if the inner macro inserts a comma, you get the original error

```
    30         %macro comma_macro(left, right);
    31          %put NOTE: comma_macro: left is &left;
    32          %put NOTE: comma_macro: right is &right;
    33          &left., &right.
    34         %mend;
    35         %outer_macro(left, %comma_macro(midle, right));
    NOTE: comma_macro: left is midle
    NOTE: comma_macro: right is right
    ERROR: More positional parameters found than defined.
```

**I would expect `%str` to resolve this, but it does not. Why?**

```
    36         %outer_macro(left, %str(%comma_macro(midle, right)));
    NOTE: comma_macro: left is midle, right
    NOTE: comma_macro: right is
    ERROR: More positional parameters found than defined.
```

### Context

For your information: I need this because I wrote a macro to list a few fields I should query from a database and I need to pass my sql to the database via another macro.

```
%run_SQL(select key, %list_fields(some_arguments), from something);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote the output from %COMMA_MACRO

```
33          %macro comma_macro(left, right);
34            %put NOTE: comma_macro: left is &left;
35            %put NOTE: comma_macro: right is &right;
36            %nrbquote(&left., &right.)
37            %mend;
38         %macro outer_macro(left, right);
39            %put NOTE: outer_macro: left is &left;
40            %put NOTE: outer_macro: right is &right;
41            %mend;
42         %outer_macro(left, %comma_macro(midle, right));
NOTE: comma_macro: left is midle
NOTE: comma_macro: right is right
NOTE: outer_macro: left is left
NOTE: outer_macro: right is midle, right
```

Comment: or %outer_macro(left, %nrbquote(%comma_macro(midle, right))); when %COMMA_MACRO does not quote the result.  Maybe Quentin will come along and explain it all.

Answer (score 5):

The problem you have is that `%str` masks characters during macro *compilation*, not during macro *execution*.  So, the macro call compiles appropriately, executes `%comma_macro`, but then once that's executed, the values are no longer quoted (as `%str` has already done its thing). It won't mask the values a *second* time.

That's evidenced further by the fact that your `%comma_macro` call is also wrong.  It masks the `,`, which then leads to `%comma_macro` thinking `midle,right` is the first argument (identically to if you'd used the `%str` inside the macro parentheses).

Note that SAS specifically mentions this practice as dangerous in [the %str documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#z3514str.htm):

> **Do not use %STR to enclose other macro functions or macro invocations that have a list of parameter values.**
>   Because %STR masks parentheses without a match, the macro processor does not recognize the arguments of a function or the parameter values of a macro invocation.

`%quote` is identical to `%str`, except it [masks characters during resolution](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#z3514quote.htm):

> %QUOTE and %NRQUOTE mask the same items as %STR and %NRSTR, respectively. However, %STR and %NRSTR mask constant text instead of a resolved value. And, %STR and %NRSTR work when a macro compiles, while %QUOTE and %NRQUOTE work when a macro executes.

In your example, replacing `%str` with `%quote` would work perfectly well.  I would argue [`%bquote`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/mcrolref/61885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#z3514bquote.htm) is probably the preferred choice, however, as it provides additional protection for unmatched quotation marks. I've always assumed the `b` in `%bquote` stood for `better`, and never seen a reason to use `%quote` over it.

> The %BQUOTE and %NRBQUOTE functions mask a character string or resolved value of a text expression during execution of a macro or macro language statement.

That sounds like what you're doing to me.  You don't need to use `%NRBQUOTE`, unless `& %` characters might be in the result.

The table of macro quoting timelines:

```
Quoting Type  | Occurs At       | Mask details
%str          | Compilation     | Unmatched Quotations/Parens with %
%nrstr        | Compilation     | Same as %str plus & %
%quote        | Execution       | Same as %str
%nrquote      | Execution       | Same as %quote plus & %
%bquote       | Execution       | Unmatched quotes/parens automatically
%nrbquote     | Execution       | Same as %bquote plus & %
%superq       | Execution       | Only variable and without &, same list as %nbrquote
 (continuned)                   | Does not attempt to resolve anything inside of variable
```

Comment: I think officially the B in %BQUOTE stands for "blind", as in "quote whatever value comes from resolving this macro expression, even though I cannot see that value in this code." As opposed to %STR/%NRSTR, which quote symbols you can see. Agree, %BQUOTE replaced %QUOTE. I have NEVER found %NRBQUOTE useful, since it doesn't actually prevent the macro processor from trying to resolve % or &. I think %SUPERQ() does what %NRBQUOTE should have done. I believe Master Whitlock has written that %STR %NRSTR %BQUOTE %SUPERQ are a comprehensive suite of quoting functions that should suffice.

Comment: `%QUOTE/%BQUOTE` both have that functionality though - they're both execution time, not compile time.  It's very possible it means blind, but in my head I've always thought Better :)  And - I agree with Ian, though I've run into at least one edge case where NBRQUOTE was what I wanted; I don't recall what that was.

Comment: Fair point. Perhaps blind to whether there is an unmatched quote mark. %Bquote can handle these %Quote can't (unless they are marked). But agree, %Bquote is definitely better, and came after %quote. So perhaps they just had to give it a new name. Would definitely be interested in an example where %NRBQUOTE is useful and does not generate failed resolution warnings.